# Point on Polygon overlay in ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, point-in-polygon

I am not sure how to do this task in Python. I have a point shapefile and I want to overlay with polygon layer to get all the polygons for each point. After this would like to loop through all the records to get the attributes.

```py
wellRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("H:\points.shp") 

for wellRow in wellRows:
    wellPoint = wellRow.SHAPE #Not sure how to have shape as input...
    landRows = arcpy.SearchCursor("H:\Poly.shp", "", "", "","")

    for landRow in landRows:
        print landRow.NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

This becomes simpler in 10.1, when you get access to tokens in the [data access module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/):

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("H:\points.shp", "SHAPE@") as wellRows:
    for wellRow in wellRows:
        wellPoint = row[0]
```

If you are using Arcmap < 10.1, use the following to access the "Shape" field:

```
shpname = arcpy.Describe("H:\points.shp").ShapeFieldName
wellRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("H:\points.shp") 

for wellRow in wellRows:
    wellPoint = wellRow.getValue(shpname)
```